# Square API: can List Orders be filtered by state?

Tags: square-connect

I only care about orders that are "PENDING".

Is there a way to filter by [Order.state](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#enum-orderstate) when Listing Orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such filter in the API. You'll have to do it in your client application.